# ASP.Net web API services usage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

There are two separate projects. I want to run asp.net mvc projesine with service.

I would also like to use the web api service as a service.

How can I make the connection between Asp.net MVC and Asp.net WebApi. I will use the controller in the web API.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally , You can Call them Even if they are In a Separated Projects 
as long as they are in the same solution, 
Specify the Route To the Api and it will work,

if they are NOT on the same solution you can ingrate them to gather or host them both on a local host and use https://localhost:"The-Port"/{Route}

Hope that Helps ,